# Non-differentiable variational calculus (Dido's problem)

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

I wonder what is  the alternative to Euler-Lagrange equations when we have non-differentiability issues. I'll give an example:

Dido's problem can be stated as:

> Find the figure bounded by a line which has the maximum area for a given perimeter.

The solution I've seen goes as follows.

Let's consider the $X$ axis to be the line and $y(x)$ the curve that encloses the figure. We want to optimize the area:

$$\int y(x) dx$$
A possible solution would be to apply Lagrange multipliers, where the constraint is:

$$\mathrm{perimeter}=\int\sqrt{1+y'^2(x)}dx $$

So the Lagrangian is:

$$L(y,y')=y+\lambda\sqrt{1+y'^2}$$

And we just have to apply Euler-Lagrange equations.

I have some doubts on the type of curves we are considering. For example, if the fuction takes negative values, the area would be:

$$\int|y(x)|dx$$

Which in general, will give rise to a non differentiable Lagrangian.

**So it seems we are discarding non-differentiable curves and those with negative values. Is there any way to show this type of curves  won't give rise to maximum area?** I guess that if the function is at least piecewise differentiable, we could divide the intregral into several intervals. I'm fine if the proof is a bit handy wavy.